# 5 x 5 matrix over Z_2

Tags: matrices

Is there a 5 x 5 invertible matrix such that

$M+M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ ?

I tried solving this algebraically by multiplying both sides by M but when I do this there are too many unknowns.

Thanks

Comment: Here by $\mathbb Z_2$ do you mean the integers mod $2$, or do you mean the $2$-adic integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, do this over a field $\mathbb F$ of characteristic $2$.
Let $R$ be your right side matrix and $e = (1,1,1,1,1)^T$. Since $RMe = MRe = Me$, and $R$ has one-dimensional column space, $Me$ must be a scalar multiple of $e$, 
say $t e$, where $t \in \mathbb F \backslash \{0\}$.  Then we must have $M e + M^{-1} e = (t + 1/t) e = Re = e$, and $t + 1/t = 1$. Thus the polynomial $t^2 + t + 1 = 0$ has a root in the field $\mathbb F$. 
Now this has no root in the field $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, so that settles the OP's question.  On the other hand, in a field where this does have a root $\alpha$, $M = I + (\alpha + 1) R$ is a solution.

Comment: What is $R$? I don't see anything called $R$ in the original question.  I assume that $R$ is the matrix that has $1$ in every entry?

Comment: Sorry, left that out: editing.